# Looping over Ruby hash and filtering using each method

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
self.board.each { |position, piece| 
    if piece == 'test'
      ...
    end
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to filter what my hash loops over? Instead of placing the If statement inside it?

I tried the 'Select' method on the hash with the 'each' method but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your code is idiomatic; I don't see any way to improve its performance or clarity.  You could use `select` for a "pre-filter" like so:

```
self.board.select{|a,b|b=='test'}.each do |position,piece|
  # Now you are only looking at "test" pieces...
end
```

But it will perform roughly two iterations of the loop (instead of just one) and isn't as clear as your code, in my opinion.  The only minor improvement I could imagine is as follows:

```
self.board.each do |position,piece|
  next unless piece == 'test'
  # ...
end
```

This way you don't need another level of indentation for your "main" logic.

Comment: Yes I tend to agree with you after looking at your solution maerics. Thanks for the solution anyway, it works perfectly but I'll stick to my current code :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to filter out the element whose key is "three" for instance:

`hash.reject {|key ,value| key == "three" }.each{...}`

That works with any condition.

Answer (score 0):

Only a little variant:

```
self.board.each { |position, piece| 
  next unless piece == 1
  puts position
}
```

Instead of a if/end the each-loop will skip over the items you are not interested in.